# Python. Tkinter. Передача индексов списков в Label

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, gui

я не могу понять как передавать номер выбранного в Combobox элемента списка как в качестве индекса другого списка.
Другими словами как сделать так, чтобы выбор имени

> srcValute["values"] = ...

был сопряжен с выбором значения

> lbl0 = Label(tab1,text=values)

для последующей передачи его в текстовый ярлык ? 
Да и вообще уместна ли такая передача ?

Привожу исходный код :

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import urllib.request
import xml.dom.minidom

response = urllib.request.urlopen(\
"http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=20/05/2000")
print(response)
print('result code: ' + str(response.getcode()))
print(response)
print('result code: ' + str(response.getcode()))
#read_page = response.read()
#print(read_page.decode('utf-8'))
#print(read_page)
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(response)

valute = doc.getElementsByTagName("Valute")
names = []
values = []
for val in valute:
   name = val.getElementsByTagName("Name")[0]
   names.append(name.firstChild.data)
   value = val.getElementsByTagName("Value")[0]
   values.append(value.firstChild.data)

selByName = [i for i in names]

window = Tk()
window.title("Конвертер валют")

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control) 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control) 
tab_control.add(tab1, text="Курс")
tab_control.add(tab2, text="График")

srcValute = ttk.Combobox(tab1)
srcValute["values"] = selByName
srcValute.grid(column=0, row=0)

srcValute.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",lambda x : print(names[:1]))

convValute = ttk.Combobox(tab1)
convValute["values"] = selByName
convValute.grid(column=2, row=0)



txt = Entry(tab1)
#lbl0 = Label(tab1,text=)
#lbl0.grid(row=2,column=5,sticky="w")

tab_control.pack(expand=1,fill='both')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Что значит "был сопряжен с выбором значения"? Нужно чтобы в Label проставлялось выбранное значение?

Comment: Нужно чтобы в Label было значение индекса выбранного элемента

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К событию `<<ComboboxSelected>>` нужно привязать функцию, которая будет проставлять в label индекс элемента:

```
lbl0 = Label(tab1)
lbl0.grid(row=2,column=5,sticky="w")


def set_label_text(event):
    lbl0["text"] = str(srcValute.current())


srcValute.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", set_label_text)
```